# Windows 10 Ubuntu WSL Coloring issue

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Not sure when this started as I haven't used WSL for development in a while but I had previously set up colors mimicking Ubuntu some time ago using the color palette in the Properties settings.
Previously the text in the JSON output was yellow but now they are the same color as the background:

[image]

This is how JSON looks now, the actual JSON text is (copy/pasted from the console):

```
QIPJS: { document_id: '207867',
  receiver_data:
   { externalId: '1003',...}
```

Which color is used for the string in the JSON output above?
I run Serverless/Node.js on the WSL console and execute as `sls invoke local --function xxx`

Comment: The colours used will depend on the specific program you're using to display the the text, but you haven't said what program you're using.

Comment: Thanks, added info about Serverless/Node.js bein the program I run

Comment: Try this terminal emulator - https://github.com/goreliu/wsl-terminal, i'm using it and it renders colors properly. There's a newer one it seems, [here](https://github.com/mintty/wsltty), did not try this one but also looks promising. The default terminal emulator that comes with WSL (console host or whatever it's called now) is great but still has some color issues in some applications (i.e. vim). I'm sure there's a way to fix that but `wsl-terminal` just works and you can reinvest that effort somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks, @evilSnobu, I had a look and the newer one seems less "hacky-ish" to get running... I'd prefer getting the original one working though...